# I want to refactor two nested foreaches and break it into separate functions

Tags: php, refactoring

I have a big foreach where I do many calculations and it looks too messy and bad, that's why I want to break it into more functions but I don't know how since I don't know what arguments should I pass to my sub-functions
Here is my code

```
    $dataset                = 'supplier_invoices';
$SupplierInvoice        = new Dbm_Supplier($dataset);
$totalValoare               = 0;
$costAdaos                  = 0;
$totalTva_neex              = 0;
$totalVal_cu_tva            = 0;

$totalValoareCantitateNegativaProduseFacturate                  = 0;
$costAdaosCantitateNegativaProduseFacturate                     = 0;
$totalTva_neexCantitateNegativaProduseFacturate                 = 0;
$totalVal_cu_tvaCantitateNegativaProduseFacturate               = 0;

$totalValoarePozitivaProduseFacturate               = 0;
$costAdaosPozitivaProduseFacturate                  = 0;
$totalTva_neexPozitivaProduseFacturate              = 0;
$totalVal_cu_tvaPozitivaProduseFacturate            = 0;

$totalValoareProduseFurnizor = 0;
$costAdaosProduseFurnizor = 0;
$totalTva_neexProduseFurnizor = 0;
$totalVal_cu_tvaProduseFurnizor = 0;

$totalValoareProduseFurnizorReturnate = 0;
$costAdaosProduseFurnizorReturnate = 0;
$totalTva_neexProduseFurnizorReturnate = 0;
$totalVal_cu_tvaProduseFurnizorReturnate = 0;


foreach ($invoices as $invoice)
{
    $data = $SupplierInvoice->findFirst(array('supplier_invoice_id'=>$invoice['supplier_invoice_id']));
    $data = $data['results'];
    $invoiceCalculus = new InvoiceSupplierCalculus($data['supplier_invoice_date'], $data['currency_rate']);
    $products               = $SupplierInvoice->getProductsForInvoice($invoice['supplier_invoice_id']);
    foreach ($products as $product)
    {
        $calculus = $invoiceCalculus->getCalculus($product);
        $valoare = $calculus['default_currency_value'];
        $adaos_com = $calculus['adaos_com'];
        $tva_neex  = $calculus['tva_neex'];
        $val_cu_tva = $calculus['val_cu_tva'];

        $totalValoare               +=   $valoare;
        $costAdaos                  +=   $adaos_com;
        $totalTva_neex              +=   $tva_neex;
        $totalVal_cu_tva            +=   $val_cu_tva;
        $totalVal_cu_tva             =  number_format($totalVal_cu_tva,2,'.','');

        if($product['invoice_quantity'] < 0)
        {
            $totalValoareCantitateNegativaProduseFacturate                +=   -1 * abs($valoare);
            $costAdaosCantitateNegativaProduseFacturate                   +=   -1 * abs($adaos_com);
            $totalTva_neexCantitateNegativaProduseFacturate               +=   -1 * abs($tva_neex);
            $totalVal_cu_tvaCantitateNegativaProduseFacturate             +=   -1 * abs($val_cu_tva);
            $totalVal_cu_tvaCantitateNegativaProduseFacturate             =  number_format($totalVal_cu_tvaCantitateNegativaProduseFacturate,2,'.','');
        }
        else
        {
            $totalValoarePozitivaProduseFacturate               +=   abs($valoare);
            $costAdaosPozitivaProduseFacturate                  +=   abs($adaos_com);
            $totalTva_neexPozitivaProduseFacturate              +=   abs($tva_neex);
            $totalVal_cu_tvaPozitivaProduseFacturate            +=   abs($val_cu_tva);
            $totalVal_cu_tvaPozitivaProduseFacturate             =  number_format($totalVal_cu_tvaPozitivaProduseFacturate,2,'.','');
        }

        if($product['product_quantity'] < 0)
        {
            $totalValoareProduseFurnizorReturnate  +=   $valoare;
            $costAdaosProduseFurnizorReturnate +=   $adaos_com;
            $totalTva_neexProduseFurnizorReturnate  +=   $tva_neex;
            $totalVal_cu_tvaProduseFurnizorReturnate +=   $val_cu_tva;
            $totalVal_cu_tvaProduseFurnizorReturnate =  number_format($totalVal_cu_tvaProduseFurnizorReturnate,2,'.','');
        }
        else
        {
            $totalValoareProduseFurnizor +=   $valoare;
            $costAdaosProduseFurnizor +=   $adaos_com;
            $totalTva_neexProduseFurnizor +=   $tva_neex;
            $totalVal_cu_tvaProduseFurnizor +=   $val_cu_tva;
            $totalVal_cu_tvaProduseFurnizor =  number_format($totalVal_cu_tvaProduseFurnizor,2,'.','');
        }

    }
}
```

This code calculates prices of products listed on invoices. If a product has a minus before its quantity then it means that the product was returned and its price should be subtracted from the final total.

Comment: Looks like a lot of repetition when calculating whether it's a return or not. Probably can group those together and move away from an if/else. Probably put that into a separate function or method. Variables like `$totalValoareCantitateNegativaProduseFacturat` are way too long. A lot of related variables which should probably be grouped together. Might try moving over to an array of some sort. After all this looping, and after doing totally up of some sort, what variable or variables are you using, and how are you using it? Probably a much easier way to populate the variable(s) with the items.

Comment: You might also want to separate concerns like looking up an invoice id, and getting all line items on it. Probably can do this sort of logic directly on the database if you write a query for it.

Comment: And honestly consider a less-nightmarish variable naming scheme to assist in readability.

Answer (score 1):

I would encapsulate all of the calculations and accumulated variables in a class, and in the loop just pass the necessary values into a function on the class that handles the logic.

```php
<?php
class InvoiceTotalsAccumulator
{
    private $totalValoare  = 0;
    private $costAdaos     = 0;
    private $totalTvaNeex  = 0;
    private $totalValCuTva = 0;
    
    private $totalValoareCantitateNegativaProduseFacturate  = 0;
    private $costAdaosCantitateNegativaProduseFacturate     = 0;
    private $totalTvaNeexCantitateNegativaProduseFacturate  = 0;
    private $totalValCuTvaCantitateNegativaProduseFacturate = 0;
    
    private $totalValoarePozitivaProduseFacturate  = 0;
    private $costAdaosPozitivaProduseFacturate     = 0;
    private $totalTvaNeexPozitivaProduseFacturate  = 0;
    private $totalValCuTvaPozitivaProduseFacturate = 0;
    
    private $totalValoareProduseFurnizor  = 0;
    private $costAdaosProduseFurnizor     = 0;
    private $totalTvaNeexProduseFurnizor  = 0;
    private $totalValCuTvaProduseFurnizor = 0;
    
    private $totalValoareProduseFurnizorReturnate  = 0;
    private $costAdaosProduseFurnizorReturnate     = 0;
    private $totalTvaNeexProduseFurnizorReturnate  = 0;
    private $totalValCuTvaProduseFurnizorReturnate = 0;
    
    public function addProductCalculus($invoiceQuantity, $productQuantity, $valoare, $adaosCom, $tvaNeex, $valCuTva)
    {
        $this->totalValoare  += $valoare;
        $this->costAdaos     += $adaosCom;
        $this->totalTvaNeex  += $tvaNeex;
        $this->totalValCuTva += $valCuTva;
        
        if ($invoiceQuantity < 0)
        {
            $this->totalValoareCantitateNegativaProduseFacturate  += -1 * abs($valoare);
            $this->costAdaosCantitateNegativaProduseFacturate     += -1 * abs($adaosCom;
            $this->totalTvaNeexCantitateNegativaProduseFacturate  += -1 * abs($tvaNeex);
            $this->totalValCuTvaCantitateNegativaProduseFacturate += -1 * abs($valCuTva);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->totalValoarePozitivaProduseFacturate  += abs($valoare);
            $this->costAdaosPozitivaProduseFacturate     += abs($adaosCom;
            $this->totalTva_neexPozitivaProduseFacturate += abs($tvaNeex);
            $this->totalValCuTvaPozitivaProduseFacturate += abs($valCuTva);
        }
        
        if ($productQuantity < 0)
        {
            $this->totalValoareProduseFurnizorReturnate  += $valoare;
            $this->costAdaosProduseFurnizorReturnate     += $adaosCom;
            $this->totalTva_neexProduseFurnizorReturnate += $tvaNeex;
            $this->totalValCuTvaProduseFurnizorReturnate += $valCuTva;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->totalValoareProduseFurnizor  += $valoare;
            $this->costAdaosProduseFurnizor     += $adaosCom;
            $this->totalTva_neexProduseFurnizor += $tvaNeex;
            $this->totalValCuTvaProduseFurnizor += $valCuTva;
        }
    }
    
    private function _formatNumberForOutput($number)
    {
        return number_format($number, 2, '.', '');
    }
    
    public function getTotalValoare()
    {
        return $this->totalValoare;
    }
    
    public function setTotalValoare(int $totalValoare)
    {
        $this->totalValoare = $totalValoare;
    }
    
    public function getCostAdaos()
    {
        return $this->costAdaos;
    }
    
    public function setCostAdaos(int $costAdaos)
    {
        $this->costAdaos = $costAdaos;
    }
    
    public function getTotalTvaNeex()
    {
        return $this->totalTvaNeex;
    }
    
    public function setTotalTvaNeex(int $totalTvaNeex)
    {
        $this->totalTvaNeex = $totalTvaNeex;
    }
    
    public function getTotalValCuTva()
    {
        return $this->_formatNumberForOutput($this->totalValCuTva);
    }
    
    public function setTotalValCuTva(int $totalValCuTva)
    {
        $this->totalValCuTva = $totalValCuTva;
    }
    
    public function getTotalValoareCantitateNegativaProduseFacturate()
    {
        return $this->totalValoareCantitateNegativaProduseFacturate;
    }
    
    public function setTotalValoareCantitateNegativaProduseFacturate(int $totalValoareCantitateNegativaProduseFacturate)
    {
        $this->totalValoareCantitateNegativaProduseFacturate = $totalValoareCantitateNegativaProduseFacturate;
    }
    
    public function getCostAdaosCantitateNegativaProduseFacturate()
    {
        return $this->costAdaosCantitateNegativaProduseFacturate;
    }
    
    public function setCostAdaosCantitateNegativaProduseFacturate(int $costAdaosCantitateNegativaProduseFacturate)
    {
        $this->costAdaosCantitateNegativaProduseFacturate = $costAdaosCantitateNegativaProduseFacturate;
    }
    
    public function getTotalTvaNeexCantitateNegativaProduseFacturate()
    {
        return $this->totalTvaNeexCantitateNegativaProduseFacturate;
    }
    
    public function setTotalTvaNeexCantitateNegativaProduseFacturate(int $totalTvaNeexCantitateNegativaProduseFacturate)
    {
        $this->totalTvaNeexCantitateNegativaProduseFacturate = $totalTvaNeexCantitateNegativaProduseFacturate;
    }
    
    public function getTotalValCuTvaCantitateNegativaProduseFacturate()
    {
        return $this->_formatNumberForOutput($this->totalValCuTvaCantitateNegativaProduseFacturate);
    }
    
    public function setTotalValCuTvaCantitateNegativaProduseFacturate(int $totalValCuTvaCantitateNegativaProduseFacturate)
    {
        $this->totalValCuTvaCantitateNegativaProduseFacturate = $totalValCuTvaCantitateNegativaProduseFacturate;
    }
    
    public function getTotalValoarePozitivaProduseFacturate()
    {
        return $this->totalValoarePozitivaProduseFacturate;
    }
    
    public function setTotalValoarePozitivaProduseFacturate(int $totalValoarePozitivaProduseFacturate)
    {
        $this->totalValoarePozitivaProduseFacturate = $totalValoarePozitivaProduseFacturate;
    }
    
    public function getCostAdaosPozitivaProduseFacturate()
    {
        return $this->costAdaosPozitivaProduseFacturate;
    }
    
    public function setCostAdaosPozitivaProduseFacturate(int $costAdaosPozitivaProduseFacturate)
    {
        $this->costAdaosPozitivaProduseFacturate = $costAdaosPozitivaProduseFacturate;
    }
    
    public function getTotalTvaNeexPozitivaProduseFacturate()
    {
        return $this->totalTvaNeexPozitivaProduseFacturate;
    }
    
    public function setTotalTvaNeexPozitivaProduseFacturate(int $totalTvaNeexPozitivaProduseFacturate)
    {
        $this->totalTvaNeexPozitivaProduseFacturate = $totalTvaNeexPozitivaProduseFacturate;
    }
    
    public function getTotalValCuTvaPozitivaProduseFacturate()
    {
        return $this->_formatNumberForOutput($this->totalValCuTvaPozitivaProduseFacturate);
    }
    
    public function setTotalValCuTvaPozitivaProduseFacturate(int $totalValCuTvaPozitivaProduseFacturate)
    {
        $this->totalValCuTvaPozitivaProduseFacturate = $totalValCuTvaPozitivaProduseFacturate;
    }
    
    public function getTotalValoareProduseFurnizor()
    {
        return $this->totalValoareProduseFurnizor;
    }
    
    public function setTotalValoareProduseFurnizor(int $totalValoareProduseFurnizor)
    {
        $this->totalValoareProduseFurnizor = $totalValoareProduseFurnizor;
    }
    
    public function getCostAdaosProduseFurnizor()
    {
        return $this->costAdaosProduseFurnizor;
    }
    
    public function setCostAdaosProduseFurnizor(int $costAdaosProduseFurnizor)
    {
        $this->costAdaosProduseFurnizor = $costAdaosProduseFurnizor;
    }
    
    public function getTotalTvaNeexProduseFurnizor()
    {
        return $this->totalTvaNeexProduseFurnizor;
    }
    
    public function setTotalTvaNeexProduseFurnizor(int $totalTvaNeexProduseFurnizor)
    {
        $this->totalTvaNeexProduseFurnizor = $totalTvaNeexProduseFurnizor;
    }
    
    public function getTotalValCuTvaProduseFurnizor()
    {
        return $this->_formatNumberForOutput($this->totalValCuTvaProduseFurnizor);
    }
    
    public function setTotalValCuTvaProduseFurnizor(int $totalValCuTvaProduseFurnizor)
    {
        $this->totalValCuTvaProduseFurnizor = $totalValCuTvaProduseFurnizor;
    }
    
    public function getTotalValoareProduseFurnizorReturnate()
    {
        return $this->totalValoareProduseFurnizorReturnate;
    }
    
    public function setTotalValoareProduseFurnizorReturnate(int $totalValoareProduseFurnizorReturnate)
    {
        $this->totalValoareProduseFurnizorReturnate = $totalValoareProduseFurnizorReturnate;
    }
    
    public function getCostAdaosProduseFurnizorReturnate()
    {
        return $this->costAdaosProduseFurnizorReturnate;
    }
    
    public function setCostAdaosProduseFurnizorReturnate(int $costAdaosProduseFurnizorReturnate)
    {
        $this->costAdaosProduseFurnizorReturnate = $costAdaosProduseFurnizorReturnate;
    }
    
    public function getTotalTvaNeexProduseFurnizorReturnate()
    {
        return $this->totalTvaNeexProduseFurnizorReturnate;
    }
    
    public function setTotalTvaNeexProduseFurnizorReturnate(int $totalTvaNeexProduseFurnizorReturnate)
    {
        $this->totalTvaNeexProduseFurnizorReturnate = $totalTvaNeexProduseFurnizorReturnate;
    }
    
    public function getTotalValCuTvaProduseFurnizorReturnate()
    {
        return $this->_formatNumberForOutput($this->totalValCuTvaProduseFurnizorReturnate);
    }
    
    public function setTotalValCuTvaProduseFurnizorReturnate(int $totalValCuTvaProduseFurnizorReturnate)
    {
        $this->totalValCuTvaProduseFurnizorReturnate = $totalValCuTvaProduseFurnizorReturnate;
    }
    
    public function toArray()
    {
        return [
            'totalValoare'  => $this->getTotalValoare(),
            'costAdaos'     => $this->getCostAdaos(),
            'totalTvaNeex'  => $this->getTotalTvaNeex(),
            'totalValCuTva' => $this->getTotalValCuTva(),
            
            'totalValoareCantitateNegativaProduseFacturate'  => $this->getTotalValoareCantitateNegativaProduseFacturate(),
            'costAdaosCantitateNegativaProduseFacturate'     => $this->getCostAdaosCantitateNegativaProduseFacturate(),
            'totalTvaNeexCantitateNegativaProduseFacturate'  => $this->getTotalTvaNeexCantitateNegativaProduseFacturate(),
            'totalValCuTvaCantitateNegativaProduseFacturate' => $this->getTotalValCuTvaCantitateNegativaProduseFacturate(),
            
            'totalValoarePozitivaProduseFacturate'  => $this->getTotalValoarePozitivaProduseFacturate(),
            'costAdaosPozitivaProduseFacturate'     => $this->getCostAdaosPozitivaProduseFacturate(),
            'totalTvaNeexPozitivaProduseFacturate'  => $this->getTotalTvaNeexPozitivaProduseFacturate(),
            'totalValCuTvaPozitivaProduseFacturate' => $this->getTotalValCuTvaPozitivaProduseFacturate(),
            
            'totalValoareProduseFurnizor'  => $this->getTotalValoareProduseFurnizor(),
            'costAdaosProduseFurnizor'     => $this->getCostAdaosProduseFurnizor(),
            'totalTvaNeexProduseFurnizor'  => $this->getTotalTvaNeexProduseFurnizor(),
            'totalValCuTvaProduseFurnizor' => $this->getTotalValCuTvaProduseFurnizor(),
            
            'totalValoareProduseFurnizorReturnate'  => $this->getTotalValoareProduseFurnizorReturnate(),
            'costAdaosProduseFurnizorReturnate'     => $this->getCostAdaosProduseFurnizorReturnate(),
            'totalTvaNeexProduseFurnizorReturnate'  => $this->getTotalTvaNeexProduseFurnizorReturnate(),
            'totalValCuTvaProduseFurnizorReturnate' => $this->getTotalvalcutvaprodusefurnizorreturnate(),
        ];
    }
}
```

Then the loop becomes dead simple:

```php
<?php

$dataset         = 'supplier_invoices';
$SupplierInvoice = new Dbm_Supplier($dataset);

$accumulator = new InvoiceTotalsAccumulator();

foreach ($invoices as $invoice)
{
    $data            = $SupplierInvoice->findFirst(['supplier_invoice_id' => $invoice['supplier_invoice_id']]);
    $data            = $data['results'];
    $invoiceCalculus = new InvoiceSupplierCalculus($data['supplier_invoice_date'], $data['currency_rate']);
    $products        = $SupplierInvoice->getProductsForInvoice($invoice['supplier_invoice_id']);
    
    foreach ($products as $product)
    {
        $calculus = $invoiceCalculus->getCalculus($product);
        
        $accumulator->addProductCalculus(
            $product['invoice_quantity'],
            $product['product_quantity'],
            $calculus['default_currency_value'],
            $calculus['adaos_com'],
            $calculus['tva_neex'],
            $calculus['val_cu_tva']
        );
    }
}
```

If this were my project, I would probably create some sort of DTO class to set the values into and pass an instance of it to the `addProductCalculus` function instead of the 6 different parameters, but that's probably overkill.